# Can't multiply some items by 1000 without kicking out the decimal places

Tags: python, python-3.x

After eliminating a letter `B` from some items, I can't multiply them by 1000 without kicking out the decimal places.

If I try like `int(float(item[:-1])) * 1000`, the decimal places are removed in the first place, and I get wrong answers.

However, I get this error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '92.96'` when I try something like below.

```
items = ['92.96B','85.4B','33B']

for item in items:
    converted_item = int(item[:-1]) * 1000
    print(converted_item)
```

Expected output:

```
92960
85400
33000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `int()` convert them to `float()`, then multiply by 1000 and finally convert them to `int()`

*You cannot directly use `int()` on a string representing a floating number.*

```
items = ['92.96B','85.4B','33B']

for item in items:
    converted_item = int(float(item[:-1]) * 1000)
    print(converted_item)


#output
92960
85400
33000
```

Comment: As an addon to this, as for why `int(float(item[:-1])) * 1000` gives the wrong answer. Let's take `"92.96B"` for example. Doing `item[:-1]` gives `"92.96"`. Casting it to a float gives `92.96`. Casting that to a int would truncate it to the integer value of `92`. Then multiplying by 1000 would give `92000`. Multiplying by 1000 before casting it to an integer would turn `92.96` into `92960.00`, and then the casting would turn it into `92960`.